# Transfering C++ CRC16 modbus rtu calculator to python

Tags: python, crc, crc16

Please excuse me if the question will be simple, I'm kinda new with CRC.

I've got cpp CRC16 func with defined crc table and I want exactly the same results in python. I used some libraries, but all of them gave me different results. The reason is probably with diference in crc tables, but all the algorithms that I found don't have defined tables that I can  swap with mine.

Original func:

```
uint16_t CRC16(const uint8_t *data, int len)
{
    static const uint16_t crc_table[] = {
      0x0000,0x8005,0x800F,0x000A,0x801B,0x001E,0x0014,0x8011,
      0x8033,0x0036,0x003C,0x8039,0x0028,0x802D,0x8027,0x0022,
      0x8063,0x0066,0x006C,0x8069,0x0078,0x807D,0x8077,0x0072,
      0x0050,0x8055,0x805F,0x005A,0x804B,0x004E,0x0044,0x8041,
      0x80C3,0x00C6,0x00CC,0x80C9,0x00D8,0x80DD,0x80D7,0x00D2,
      0x00F0,0x80F5,0x80FF,0x00FA,0x80EB,0x00EE,0x00E4,0x80E1,
      0x00A0,0x80A5,0x80AF,0x00AA,0x80BB,0x00BE,0x00B4,0x80B1,
      0x8093,0x0096,0x009C,0x8099,0x0088,0x808D,0x8087,0x0082,
      0x8183,0x0186,0x018C,0x8189,0x0198,0x819D,0x8197,0x0192,
      0x01B0,0x81B5,0x81BF,0x01BA,0x81AB,0x01AE,0x01A4,0x81A1,
      0x01E0,0x81E5,0x81EF,0x01EA,0x81FB,0x01FE,0x01F4,0x81F1,
      0x81D3,0x01D6,0x01DC,0x81D9,0x01C8,0x81CD,0x81C7,0x01C2,
      0x0140,0x8145,0x814F,0x014A,0x815B,0x015E,0x0154,0x8151,
      0x8173,0x0176,0x017C,0x8179,0x0168,0x816D,0x8167,0x0162,
      0x8123,0x0126,0x012C,0x8129,0x0138,0x813D,0x8137,0x0132,
      0x0110,0x8115,0x811F,0x011A,0x810B,0x010E,0x0104,0x8101,
      0x8303,0x0306,0x030C,0x8309,0x0318,0x831D,0x8317,0x0312,
      0x0330,0x8335,0x833F,0x033A,0x832B,0x032E,0x0324,0x8321,
      0x0360,0x8365,0x836F,0x036A,0x837B,0x037E,0x0374,0x8371,
      0x8353,0x0356,0x035C,0x8359,0x0348,0x834D,0x8347,0x0342,
      0x03C0,0x83C5,0x83CF,0x03CA,0x83DB,0x03DE,0x03D4,0x83D1,
      0x83F3,0x03F6,0x03FC,0x83F9,0x03E8,0x83ED,0x83E7,0x03E2,
      0x83A3,0x03A6,0x03AC,0x83A9,0x03B8,0x83BD,0x83B7,0x03B2,
      0x0390,0x8395,0x839F,0x039A,0x838B,0x038E,0x0384,0x8381,
      0x0280,0x8285,0x828F,0x028A,0x829B,0x029E,0x0294,0x8291,
      0x82B3,0x02B6,0x02BC,0x82B9,0x02A8,0x82AD,0x82A7,0x02A2,
      0x82E3,0x02E6,0x02EC,0x82E9,0x02F8,0x82FD,0x82F7,0x02F2,
      0x02D0,0x82D5,0x82DF,0x02DA,0x82CB,0x02CE,0x02C4,0x82C1,
      0x8243,0x0246,0x024C,0x8249,0x0258,0x825D,0x8257,0x0252,
      0x0270,0x8275,0x827F,0x027A,0x826B,0x026E,0x0264,0x8261,
      0x0220,0x8225,0x822F,0x022A,0x823B,0x023E,0x0234,0x8231,
      0x8213,0x0216,0x021C,0x8219,0x0208,0x820D,0x8207,0x0202
    };

    uint16_t crc_word = 0xFFFF;

    while (len--)
      crc_word = (crc_word << 8) ^ crc_table[(((crc_word >> 8) & 0x00FF) ^ *data++) & 0x00FF];

    return crc_word;
}
uint16_t crc = CRC16(((uint8_t*)&tx_frame) + 1, (int)(tx_frame.num_data_bytes + 1));
uint8_t crc1 = crc >> 8;
uint8_t crc2 = 0xFF & crc;
tx_frame.crc = crc1 + crc2 * 256;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters and name of [that CRC](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/all.htm#crc.cat.crc-16-cms) (click on link for more information):

```
width=16 poly=0x8005 init=0xffff refin=false refout=false xorout=0x0000 check=0xaee7 residue=0x0000 name="CRC-16/CMS"
```

In Python:

```
>>> import crcmod
>>> crc16 = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x18005, rev=False, initCrc=0xffff)
>>> print(hex(crc16(b'123456789')))
0xaee7
```